# FQL: Retrieving Posts on Friends wall that I posted

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am looking for an FQL query that requests all posts on my friends' walls that I have posted.
It does not matter if there is any limitation.
I tried the following:

```
SELECT post_id, message, likes.friends, comments.comment_list
FROM stream
WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) AND actor_id=me() limit 1000
```

`Source_id` --> `my friends wall`

`actor_id` --> `I posted it`

And I get an empty array back. When I used "limit 1000" I got at least one of my posts - the latest I guess. I do not know what I am doing wrong.
Am I using the wrong table? 
I do not want to get all of the posts of my friends, I just want the ones I posted to and as a logged in user this should be possible, right?